# Echo a php inside a php

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to pass out the variables to the next php form but i cant get it right. But i get this error :**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\bagongabnoy\AthanMotorcycleWebsite2\debitgo.php on line 28**

here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

include('config.php');
$accname=$_POST['accname'];
$accnum=$_POST['accnum'];
$pin=$_POST['pin'];
$cusid=$_POST['cusid'];
$grandtotal=$_POST['grandtotal'];
$transactioncode=$_POST['transactioncode'];
$trasactiondate=date("m/d/Y");
$status='Completed';
$mode='OnlinePayment';


$resultq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_bank_debit WHERE txtAccountNumber = '$accnum'");

            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultq))
            {
            $balance=$rows['intBalance'];
            //$pqs=$rows['qtysold'];
            //$left=$pql-$qty;
            //$solds=$pqs+$qty;
            $balupdate=$balance-$grandtotal;
            mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_bank_debit SET intBalance='$balupdate' WHERE txtAccountName = '$accname'");
            }

            echo '<input name="transactioncode" type="hidden" value="'<?php echo $transactioncode;?>' />';
            echo '<input name="cusid" type="hidden" value="'<?php echo $cusid;?>' />';
            echo '<input name="total" type="hidden" value="'<?php echo $total;?>' />';
            echo '<input name="grandtotal" type="hidden" value="'<?php echo $grandtotal;?>' />';
            echo '<input name="totalcharge" type="hidden" value="'<?php echo $totalcharge;?>' />';
            echo '<input name="portal" type="hidden" value="'<?php echo $portal;?>' />';
            echo '<input name="distination" type="hidden" value='<?php echo $distination;?>' />';

/*$resulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM athan_products WHERE id = '$id'");

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resulta))
            {
            $pprice=$row['price'];
            $psize=$row['product_size_name'];
            }
$total=$pprice*$qty;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO orderdetails (customer, qty, price, total, partsname, size, transactioncode) VALUES('$memid', '$qty', '$pprice', '$total', '$name', '$psize', '$transcode')");*/
header("location: cashconfirmsub.php");


?>
```

Comment: I would recommend you get a text editor that has syntax highlighting when editing PHP files. It makes finding these silly errors *significantly* easier.

Comment: Please update your mysql queries to parametrized, and at least escape the strings! Your application is begging to be hacked. This is scary considering it looks like you are dealing with real money. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Mitigation

Comment: To further Jeff's comment switch to pdo or mysqli as I believe this form of mysql query will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not the way you concatenate Strings in PHP. You aren't allowed to nesting `<?php` tags.

Instead of

```
echo '<input name="transactioncode" type="hidden" value="'<?php echo $transactioncode;?>' />';
```

Do the following:

```
echo '<input name="transactioncode" type="hidden" value="' . $transactioncode . ' />';
```

Simply add a `.` character between the parts you want to concatenate.

**Edit:**
And to finalize the answer, you should also be cautious about user inputs. They can be evil! In this case you should remove HTML characters via `htmlspecialchars()`:

```
echo '<input name="transactioncode" type="hidden" value="' . htmlspecialchars($transactioncode) . ' />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a careful look at line 28:

```
echo '<input name="distination" type="hidden" value='<?php echo $distination;?>' />';
```

The problem is fairly obvious.  Pay attention to quoting.

As a general rule: If an error report gives you a line number then take a good look a that line. Sometimes you can break the line in half and re-run the test to see if it still occurs on the same line or the next one to tell which half of the line the issue is in.  For example break your line above like this to test it:

```
echo '<input name="distination" type="hidden" 
   value='<?php echo $distination;?>' />';
```

Comment: As a general rule: If an error report gives you a line number then take a good look a that line.  Sometimes you can break the line in half and re-run the test to see if it still occurs on the same line or the next one to tell which half of the line the issue is in.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "concatenation".

You can "concatenate" (listen append) 2 strings using a dot :

```
echo "string1"."string2";
```

will display "string1string2"

You can also concatenate a string and a variable :

```
$string2 = "string2";
echo "string1".$string2;
```

So in your example, it will be :

```
echo '<input name="transactioncode" type="hidden" value="'.$transactioncode.'" />';
echo '<input name="cusid" type="hidden" value="'.$cusid.'" />';
echo '<input name="total" type="hidden" value="'.$total.'" />';
echo '<input name="grandtotal" type="hidden" value="'.$grandtotal.'" />';
echo '<input name="totalcharge" type="hidden" value="'.$totalcharge.'" />';
echo '<input name="portal" type="hidden" value="'.$portal.'" />';
echo '<input name="distination" type="hidden" value="'.$distination.'" />';
```